Microsoft Windows update may break linux dual boot
A dual boot Microsoft windows and Ubuntu works fine ... however on 20 August 2024 windows released a patch that may break this for older versions of Ubuntu.
How do I deal with this?

to quote :   On 20th August 2024, Windows released a software patch that revoked shims older than 15.8. The shim is an upstream component consumed by multiple Linux distros, including Ubuntu.
see details at https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/sbat-self-check-failed-mitigating-the-impact-of-shim-15-7-revocation-on-the-ubuntu-boot-process-for-devices-running-windows/47378/1
SOLUTION _____________________
For existing Ubuntu installations that are experiencing issues it is possible to use the following workarounds before release of new Ubuntu ISOs:
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and above:
Disable secure boot in the device BIOS settings.

Boot into Ubuntu and then, depending on release version:

24.04: You are good to go, the installed system is fine as the installed system has the 15.8 shim.
20.04/22.04: Prior to August 29th the patch is available in the proposed pocket. After August 29th the patch will become generally available and users will
simply need to update their system to upgrade to the new shim using the following command:
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade shim-signed

Boot Ubuntu a second time (with secure boot still disabled), 
this will cause the shim to reset the SBAT.

Reboot into the BIOS and re-enable secure boot.

take note of what version of this shim ubuntu package you currently have
dpkg -l|grep shim-signed

